# odoo10 how to inherit other function and update line?

Tags: python, odoo

now i'm trying code on the purchase module 
if i would like to modify a calculation of purchase order?

this code it about the calculation.

```
@api.depends('order_line.price_total')
def _amount_all(self):
    for order in self:
        amount_untaxed = amount_tax = 0.0
        for line in order.order_line:
            amount_untaxed += line.price_subtotal
            # FORWARDPORT UP TO 10.0
            if order.company_id.tax_calculation_rounding_method == 'round_globally':
                taxes = line.taxes_id.compute_all(line.price_unit, line.order_id.currency_id, line.product_qty, product=line.product_id, partner=line.order_id.partner_id)
                amount_tax += sum(t.get('amount', 0.0) for t in taxes.get('taxes', []))
            else:
                amount_tax += line.price_tax
        order.update({
            'amount_untaxed': order.currency_id.round(amount_untaxed),
            'amount_tax': order.currency_id.round(amount_tax),
            'amount_total': amount_untaxed + amount_tax,
        })
```

and this my module for inherit that code.

```
class PurchaseOrderNew(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order.line"

    new_currency = fields.Float()

 def _amount_all(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)_amount_all()

       #### i don't have no idea how to let 'new_currency' to  
     #### multiple with amount_total in order.update

    return res
```

anyone have idea about it?
I just want new_currency multiple a amount_total in order.update .
[ new_currency * amount_total ]
but no idea how to code a function like that one.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```
def _amount_all(self):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)_amount_all()
    for record in self:
       record.amount_total = self.new_currency*(amount_untaxed + amount_tax)
    return res
```

if you don't want the tax you can leave that

```
 def _amount_all(self):
     res = super(PurchaseOrderLine, self)_amount_all()
     for record in self:
         record.amount_total = self.new_currency*amount_untaxed
     return res
```